# i successfully done my app and testing in expo. now how to install in real physical device?

Tags: react-native, expo

i have successfully made and tested the application in expo. but i don't know how to install in physical device and i want to deploy it also. please help me.

while using react-native run-android showing this error.

**Android project not found. Maybe run react-native android first?**

Comment: check if you are in the project directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using expo, you should not have to make the build as a react native project. You can check in the following link the documentation in expo about how to build in Andrdoid/ios and get the apk/ipa:
https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/distribution/building-standalone-apps/

In a summary, if you have the app.json correctly configured, you just have to run:

```
expo build:android
```

Hope it helps